# Check if a node group input socket is wired?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I'd like to create node groups which behave a little differently depending on whether particular input nodes are wired or not.  Is there a way to test if they are wired or not?

I'd prefer not to use the "sentinel value" method, because I want to use the defaults as reasonable values that are set when I first place the group node, before I wire anything up, and also as a reasonable value to reset the input to when I need to.  If I set the default to a sentinel value, then I have to make that value something outside of the expected input range in order to avoid accidentally tripping it during normal use.

I'd like a `Is Input Wired(InputName:str) -> Boolean` node.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: You might want to try your luck with python scripting, I don't think what you're after is available to vanilla Blender

Answer (score 0):

Reroute thingie can be connected to multiple other nodes and if nothing is connected to it, whatever it is connected to retains default value. If you use a Compare node with both compared values set to equal unrealistic value like 9999 it will detect the difference when something else is connected to it.

[image]

It doesn't work with all available kinds of nodes, but it might be useful for some things.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think this is the same as the "sentinel value" method, which I said I'd not like to use.

Comment: OK, this doesn't work with Cycles, just with EEVEE on further testing. so you cannot do anything like that with nodes alone. Do you want a Python solution?

Comment: You can use Python with app handler same as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286890/geometry-nodes-add-a-character-inbetween-every-character-of-a-string/286897?noredirect=1#comment493755_286897)